# Cryptic crossword (jigsaw fill)

Tags: cryptic-crosswords

[image]

This is a cryptic crossword jigsaw fill: the clues are listed below, grouped by length (the only clues to have length in the standard parentheses are those having two words) and in alphabetical order in each group.  When they are solved they can be arranged to fit in the grid in exactly one way.

Once the grid is filled, the numbered squares will spell out, in order, the expected (though fictional) feminine noun for a member of a famous group.  Solvers should correct the spelling (change exactly one letter) to be the name of the group (this will produce real words in the grid, though arguably one of them is oxymoronic).  Solvers should also highlight three surnames in the grid, of members of the group, and indicate which single letter should be changed elsewhere in the grid to find a fourth surname (sadly this change does not create real words).

**3 Letters**

```
 Design a current for Malta
 Tropical bird nests in Madagascan ironwood
```

**4 Letters**

```
  Dye a duck
  Half a square metre of paper is perfect! (1-3)
  Schematic's second page missing a key...
  ...tone, for example, laid out
  Last two thirds of push for small defense
  No second impact to back of knee
  Edmund's white with age and Henry's rather less masculine
  My intention broadcast by Man, for example
  Once illuminate starting letters in manuscript notes
  Indian gardener -- bad one
  Friar's opposite is mostly Capuchin
  State occupied with Frozen Snowman
  Dialect once supported by saint
  No mate for milky white gemstone?
  Local leftovers rot badly, son
  After seconds of spiced cake, essay Stilton
```

**5 Letters**

```
  High priest sets volcanic rock above man
  American paid up for desired missing wife
  A psi-sigma initial segment defines greatest orbital distance from centre
  (Informal) Sound of car maker getting nothing
  Demeter covers with wax...
  ...time after time, O Muse!
  Lots of LA hormone takes Venetian to height of poetic inspiration
  Stinking tide stirred up after most of reef is destroyed
  Carry back: private secretary swallows quickly
  Deflection into pocket -- Fagin offers a hiding place (2-3)
  Calibrate without outliers -- sign of balance
  US Saltpetre can reverse heading, right?
  Celtic letters found in 'Van Gogh -- a memoir'
  That woman, Vanessa, extremely indicates absence of vowel
```

**6 Letters**

```
  Debauched beasts; most, worthless
  Hobbesian companion?
```

**7 Letters**

```
  Like thin plates tangling right animal
  He examines and corrects reivers' discombobulation
```

**10 Letters**

```
  Trace of life essential for glowing particle (5,5)
  Parrot plague-host is iron-addled
```

Comment: Welcome back! Haven't seen you around here in a while. (And nice puzzle!)

Comment: @Deusovi thanks :)  I go through busy patches, then I just lurk and try to remember to upvote!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The grid:

> [[image: solved grid]

The group is

> the OULIPO, a group of French experimental writers. The feminine noun is OULIPA. Correcting the latter to the former turns DIAL into DIOL and SPARK into SPORK (I'm not sure whether the intended oxymoron is SPORK itself -- spoon+fork -- or VITAL SPORK, since a spork is hardly vital).

Its members in the grid are

> CALVINO, along the top; PASTIOR, down from the P near the end of the top row; MONK, at the bottom left. The one that needs changing is AUDIN, obtained by changing O to N in AUDIO near the bottom left. (Which unfortunately kills Mr Monk, too.) Alternatively, you could change the L at the end of DIAL/DIOL into an N to get BENS reading upward. (The resulting entry could be *Celine* Dion, perfectly reasonable even if not exactly a word.) But I suspect the composer's intention is BRAFFORT, obtained by changing a K to an F on the right-hand side.
>
>   [image: solved grid with letters changed and highlighted members]

Individual solutions with explanations:

3 Letters

Design a current for Malta
 Tropical bird nests in Madagascan ironwood

> AIM (A+I+M)
>  ANI (substring: madagascANIronwood)

4 Letters

Dye a duck
  Half a square metre of paper is perfect! (1-3)
  Schematic's second page missing a key...
  ...tone, for example, laid out
  Last two thirds of push for small defense
  No second impact to back of knee
  Edmund's white with age and Henry's rather less masculine
  My intention broadcast by Man, for example
  Once illuminate starting letters in manuscript notes
  Indian gardener -- bad one
  Friar's opposite is mostly Capuchin
  State occupied with Frozen Snowman
  Dialect once supported by saint
  No mate for milky white gemstone?
  Local leftovers rot badly, son
  After seconds of spiced cake, essay Stilton

> ANIL (A+NIL)
>  A-ONE (double definition)
>  CLEF (sChematic + LE(a)F)
>  DIAL (dial tone; LAID*)
>  FORT ((ef)FORT)
>  HOCK ((s)HOCK)
>  HORE (Edmund *Spenser*; it's an old spelling of HOAR; H+(m)ORE)
>  ISLE (sounds like I'LL; the Isle of Man)
>  LIMN (first letters of L(etters) I(n) M(anuscript) N(otes))
>  MALI (MAL+I)
>  MONK (MONK(ey))
>  OLAF (LA = Louisiana in OF = with)
>  ONST (ON+ST)
>  OPAL (O+PAL)
>  ORTS (ROT*+S)
>  PAST (second letters of sPiced cAke eSsay sTilton)

5 Letters

High priest sets volcanic rock above man
  American paid up for desired missing wife
  A psi-sigma initial segment defines greatest orbital distance from centre
  (Informal) Sound of car maker getting nothing
  Demeter covers with wax...
  ...time after time, O Muse!
  Lots of LA hormone takes Venetian to height of poetic inspiration
  Stinking tide stirred up after most of reef is destroyed
  Carry back: private secretary swallows quickly
  Deflection into pocket -- Fagin offers a hiding place (2-3)
  Calibrate without outliers -- sign of balance
  US Saltpetre can reverse heading, right?
  Celtic letters found in 'Van Gogh -- a memoir'
  That woman, Vanessa, extremely indicates absence of vowel

> AARON (AA+RON)
>  ANTED (past tense of ANTE; (w)ANTED)
>  APSIS (initial segment of those words at start of clue)
>  AUDIO (AUDI+O)
>  CERES (double definition)
>  ERATO (ERA+T+O)
>  ESTRO (not sure about this; ESTRO(gen), LA implying American so e... rather than oe...? ESTRO means "inspiration" in Italian)
>  FETID ((ree)F+TIDE*)
>  GULPS (LUG< + PS)
>  IN-OFF (substring of fagINOFFers)
>  LIBRA ((ca)LIBRA(te))
>  NITER (TIN< + E + R -- thanks to @postmortes for correcting my first attempt at explaining this one, which wasn't what they'd intended and made less sense)
>  OGHAM (substring of vangOGHAMemoir)
>  SHEVA (SHE + V(aness)A)

6 Letters

Debauched beasts; most, worthless
  Hobbesian companion?

> BASEST (BEASTS*)
>  CALVIN (cryptic def referring to Bill Watterson's comics)

7 Letters

Like thin plates tangling right animal
  He examines and corrects reivers' discombobulation

> LAMINAR (RANIMAL*)
>  REVISER (REIVERS*)

10 Letters

Trace of life essential for glowing particle (5,5)
  Parrot plague-host is iron-addled

> VITAL SPARK (VITAL + SPARK)
>  ORNITHOSIS (HOSTISIRON*)

Comment: You're as fast as ever, and I commend you!  You're right on everything, although your extra member isn't the one I had in mind (that one can be found without disturbing any of the other members if you want to take another look).  And yes, my thinking for the oxymoron was that the item was non-essential rather than it itself being the oxymoron :)

Comment: I think I found your intended fourth member (and another as well).

Comment: I hope you enjoyed the clues!  (rot13)AVGRE is AVG + R + E(/rot13) and yes, (rot13) RFGEB(/rot13) is the American spelling so I felt compelled to clue it as such.

Comment: Ah, of course. In case it wasn't clear, the "?" in my explanation wasn't an expression of my uncertainty, I was suggesting that "er" and "right?" might be rough equivalents. But your way is better. I'll amend my answer. And yes, I enjoyed the clues.

Comment: Yes, you did, though well done on finding another!  I was trying to fit a decent number of them in, but I didn't like the letter-changing motif for so many entries without making it thematic and I was running out of ideas.  Green tick is incoming!

Comment: Edited to image-ify the solved grid - hope you don't mind!

Comment: I don't mind at all, of course.